# Spring Security: Redirect to invalid-session-url instead of logout-success-url on successful logout

Tags: spring, spring-security, logout, session-management

I have implemented a login-logout system with Spring Security 3.0.2, everything is fine but for this one thing: after I added a session-management tag with invalid-session-url attribute, on logout Spring would always redirect me on the invalid-session-url instead of the logout-success-url (which it correctly did before).

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

This is my configuration:

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        [...some intercept-url's...]

    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
            login-processing-url="/login-submit" default-target-url="/home"
            always-use-default-target="true" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/home?logout=true" logout-url="/login-logout" />

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/home?invalid=true" />
</http>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do You solve this ?

Answer (score 9):

By default, the logout process will first invalidate the session, hence triggering the session management to redirect to the invalid session page. By specifying invalidate-session="false" will fix this behavior.

```
<sec:logout logout-success-url="/logout" invalidate-session="false" 
delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
```

Comment: Then how do we `invalidate` the `session`.

Comment: Adding the `delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"` should be enough

Comment: It is interesting, on my local it works with `invalidate-session="true"` but not while deployed to the prod server, that's why I was confused. Anyways this solution now works on both.

Answer (score 3):

Do not confuse the logout-url attribute in the logout tag with the `invalid-session-url` attribute from session-management.

The latter is the URL to execute the action of logging out while the former is the URL being forwarded to upon a logout action.

To put it in other words, when creating a logout button, the URL for that button would be the `logout-url` value. 
Now when the logout is done, spring security, be default, will render the main application's root app path, i.e.: `http://yourserver:yourport/yourwebapp/`. This path is overridden by `invalid-session-url`. So upon logout, you will be forwarded there.

To sum up, if you don't want the behavior you're asking for, then do not use `invalid-session-url` attribute.
Hope that helps.

Comment: `invalidate-session="true"`: use `invalid-session-url`. `invalidate-session="false"`: use logout success handler url. See: [Christopher's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14131584/606662)

Comment: The requester is not talking about the `logout-url`, but rather about the `logout-success-url`, which may be somewhat hidden by the session management.