# Session expiry message in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, session-timeout

When using the Spring Security plugin in grails is there a way to configure the `invalidSessionUrl` parameter that is referred to in ([this post](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1142?%20page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel))? Or is rolling your own filter the only way to show a message?

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Security: Redirect to invalid-session-url instead of logout-success-url on successful logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601013/spring-security-redirect-to-invalid-session-url-instead-of-logout-success-url-o)

May be of help

Look at this:

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login.htm" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Had seen that link before an my question actually was how can property be configured in grails? Is there any example you can point me to?

Comment: Reported on JIRA: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-129. So it looks like using a filter is the only way at the moment