# Why when I insert the session-managment configuration into the spring-security.xml file redirect to the invalid-session-url when the user do logout?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am pretty new in Spring Security and I have the following problem with a project on which I am working on related to the log out operation when I set the **session management** setting.

So I have the following situation.

This is my **spring-security.xml** configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
      
      <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
       <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/registrati" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/sessionTimeout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/error" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/salvaRegistrazione" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/captcha.html" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/monitoraggioCandidature" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/riepilogoDettaglioRegione" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout" />
        <form-login  login-page="/login"  
                     authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
                    default-target-url="/"
                    username-parameter="nomeUtente"
                    password-parameter="password"
                    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        
        <session-management  invalid-session-url="/sessionTimeout" />
        
    </http> 
            
    <authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" >
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="datasource" 
                users-by-username-query="select des_usr_par, des_psw_par,true from TID001_ANAGPARTECIPA where des_usr_par =?"
                 authorities-by-username-query="select des_usr_par, prg_par from TID001_ANAGPARTECIPA where des_usr_par = ? "/>
                 
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

And this is the **sessionTimeout.html** view (I am using **Thymeleaf** into my project so the extension is .html and not .jsp but this is not important now).

So, how you can see in the previous **spring-security.xml** file, there is defined this setting related to the session managment:

```
<session-management  invalid-session-url="/sessionTimeout" />
```

that generate an HTTP request toward the **/sessionTimeout** resource if the session is expired (or something like this, correct me if it is a wrong assertion). This request is handled by a controller method that show the previous **sessionTimeout.html** view

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sessionTimeout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String sessionTimeout(Model model) {
    return "sessionTimeout";
}
```

As you can see into the previous **spring-security.xml** I am also managing the logout task in the Spring Security standard way, by:

```
<logout logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout" />
```

that have to redirect toward the login page associated to a request toward the **/login** resource.

This worked fine until I have not inserted the **session managment** inside my **spring-security.xml** file. The problem is that when I insert this line:

```
<session-management  invalid-session-url="/sessionTimeout" />
```

into this configuration file, when the user perform the logout operation instead to show the login page it is shown the **sessionTimeout.html** view as the session is expired or invalid.

What is the cause of this behavior? How can I fix it?

Comment: Try enabling the spring security logging (put logger org.springframework.security to debug)...it gives lots of useful information which could be helopful.

Comment: Two key classes involved in your issue are SessionManagementFilter ( and the default redirect strategy to a url) and LogoutFilter. It would be worth investigating the issue using breakpoints with your IDE.

Comment: There is a difference between an 'expired session' and an 'invalid session'. See this for example: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session. I guess you need to add `<concurrency-control expired-url="/sessionTimeout" ... />`

Comment: seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2601013/592355 ? (1st hit on `?q=invalid-session-url`;)